# Setting up Home network on Windows 7 Home with 3G modem internet connection

Tags: networking, windows-7, router, internet-connection, 3g

I am having a hard time setting up a home network on two Windows 7 machines. The situation is complicated by the fact that the internet access is via a USB 3G Modem device on the one machine.

The setup is two Windows 7 Home machines, one Desktop PC and one Laptop. The two are connected via ethernet cable to a router. There are not other devices on the router. See the image below:

*( Bummer, not enough Rep to post the image - here is an ASCII alternative: )*

**[3G Modem]<---USB--->[DesktopPC]<---CAT5--->[EthernetRouter]<---CAT5--->[Laptop]**

I've managed to share the desktop's internet connection with the laptop. I've also got some file sharing and network discovery active. I've even convinced the laptop that this is a Home Network. However, the Desktop sees 3G Modem connection as a Home network, and the ethernet connection as "Unidentified Network". Win7 Home gives no access to SecPol so I can't change this manually.

The complication comes from the fact that the Router is not the default gateway. Had my internet connection been through an ADSL line connected to the Router, or had the Router been able to dial out the 3G, then I could set the Router as default gateway, and both PCs would recognise the network and be happy. However, I can't get the same result with the setup I have.

Please advise (in detail) on how to setup internet sharing, IP addresses, gateways and DNS servers to get this to work. I know HOW to set those things, I just don't know what to set them to.

If there is a better place online for me to ask this question, please also advise. This kind of setup is quite common in the 3rd world (I'm in Namibia) where most internet is via 3G, and I don't think it's unreasonable.

Regards

Comment: I still hoping to get a working answer to this. If my question is unclear please ask for the required details.

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked so many times. Please read here:

http://geekyfaust.info/tips-and-tricks/sharing-3g-internet-connection-thru-lan-in-windows-7/

Searching google always helps.

Comment: Paul, thanks for taking the time to reply. Of course I've searched for this topic on google many times, and usually find answers exactly like the one you pointed out. However, if you read my question attentively, you'll see that the problem is not with getting the internet connection shared, this I've got working. The problem is with Windows seeing the LAN connection as "Unidentified Network". This messes up file sharing and connections for gaming on the LAN. Please read my question again. My setting are already as described in the link you posted.

Comment: I followed the instruction at the link you provided. Most of my setting were already set up that way. However, the host PC (the one with the 3G connection) still sees the network as "Unidentified Network". Any more ideas?